# Log in to remote server by using a generated public key

Tags: ssh, password, openssh, key-authentication

I have a zsh script with which I logged into a remote host to copy some folders. The system asks me each time to give the password of the local host which I want to bypass, otherwise I have to enter the passphrase many times.

I followed the following tutorial:
https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/06/perform-ssh-and-scp-without-entering-password-on-openssh/

It worked once but then it didn't work. I followed the following steps (and followed them many times again) but now it does not work anymore.

```
[local-host]$ ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/jsmith/.ssh/id_rsa):<Hit enter>
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): <Enter your passphrase here>
Enter same passphrase again:<Enter your passphrase again>
Your identification has been saved in /home/jsmith/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/jsmith/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
31:3a:5d:dc:bc:81:81:71:be:31:2b:11:b8:e8:39:a0 jsmith@local-host
```

I then copied the content of the public key from the local-host and pasted it to `/home/jsmith/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote-host and ran:

```
[remote-host]$ chmod 755 ~/.ssh
[remote-host]$ chmod 644 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

But then if I tried to log again,

```
[local-host]$ ssh  jsmith remote-host
```

But instead of having the following message:

```
Enter passphrase for key '/home/jsmith/.ssh/id_rsa': <Enter your passphrase here>
Last login: Sat Jun 07 2008 23:03:04 -0700 from 192.168.1.102
No mail.
```

I get this:

```
jsmith remote-host's password:
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Many thanks for the answer and the comments which I'll try to adress point per point:

- regarding the `-l`, I indeed did not use but instead I used `ssh jsmith@remote-host`
- I run the following with the following output

```
[local-host]$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)
Agent pid 96546
[local-host]$ env | grep SSH
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/var/folders/jq/yyp9q2fs1z5780k9l1_2ph4r0000gn/T//ssh-9ew9mjQCJWFK/agent.96545
SSH_AGENT_PID=96546
```

**EDIT 2**

So then I tried the following

```
[local-host]$ ssh-add .ssh/id_rsa
Enter passphrase for .ssh/id_rsa:
Bad passphrase, try again for .ssh/id_rsa:
```

**EDIT3**

Ok so the whole permission tree on the remote machine and local machine is the following:

```
/var/services/homes/user01/.ssh/
```

the permissions of each branch are the following (with `ls -ld <directory>` and `ls -la <file>` command (from bottom up):

For the remote machine:

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 user01 users 0 Oct  3 16:44 .ssh
drwxrwxrwx+ 1 user01 users 90 Oct
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Oct  4 09:07 homes -> /volume1/homes
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct  4 09:07 services
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root 4096 Oct  4 09:07 var
```

For the local machine:

```
drwx------  7 user02  staff   224B Oct  4 09:27 .ssh/
drwxr-xr-x+ 152 user02  staff   4.8K Oct  4 09:27 user02/
drwxr-xr-x  6 root  admin   192B Jan  1  2020 /Users/
```

Do you have an idea about what I should do next?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: the password for `id_rsa` is not your password, but the encryption password you have used when creating it

Comment: Thank you for your comment @VlastimilBurián. That's what I did. But it still doesn't work

Comment: Start by setting the correct permissions on the `~/.ssh` directory (`700`) and its contents (`600`), then try again (assuming you are able to remember the passphrase correctly).

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Kusalananda. I did `[local-host]$ chmod 700 .ssh [local-host]$ chmod 600 .ssh/* `. I try then to log in with `ssh johnsmith@remote-host` but I still get ask the passphrase of the remote-host and not the id_rsa one

Comment: The question text shows you setting the wrong permissions on the _remote_ host.

Comment: Thanks again @Kusalananda I am sorry but which exact line of the question text shows the I am setting the wrong permissions on the remote host

Comment: The only lines that contain the `chmod` commands also has a prompt saying `[remote-host]$`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run the local ssh-agent. And in the "I tried to log again" you forgot the `-l` (or, alternatively, `jsmith@remote-host`).

There's a good chance that you **did** start the agent and did the `ssh-add` part, too, but in a different session. What I do is to invoke `eval $(ssh-agent -s)` from my window-managers initialisation, that way any shell will know about the agent ...

```
$ env | grep SSH
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-LxwUgd8tuGU3/agent.1023801
SSH_AGENT_PID=1023802
```

On top of everything else, a `chmod 750 $HOME` and `chmod 700 $HOME\.ssh` are important too, though the initially described messages didn't hint at those.