# Key generated with key agent being asked several times (which is to give it only once)

Tags: ssh, key-authentication, hosting-services

Key generated with key agent being asked several times (which is to give it only once)

I am running a bash script to automate a backup on a NAS. I successfully generated a key (I had some difficulty as I had messed up the rights of the directory and file system which I resolved. The steps are in this question: [Log in to remote server by using a generated public key](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/757770/log-in-to-remote-server-by-using-a-generated-public-key)).

In the bashscript (which I run from the local) I am creating a new directory on the remote before syncing the content of the same directory from the local. Each time a directory is created, I get asked the key

```
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/user01/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

Where `user01` is the username of the local.

Ok so the whole tree is the following:

```
/var/services/homes/user01/.ssh/
```

Here are the recap of the permissions of each branch are the following (with `ls -ld <directory>` and `ls -la <file>` command (from bottom up):

For the remote machine:

```
user01@NAS:/$ ls -ld var
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root 4096 Oct  4 13:42 var
user01@NAS:/$ ls -ld var/services/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct  4 13:42 var/services/
user01@NAS:/$ ls -ld var/services/^C
user01@NAS:/$ ls -ld var
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root 4096 Oct  4 13:42 var
user01@NAS:/$ ls -ld var/services/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct  4 13:42 var/services/
user01@NAS:/$ ls -ld var/services/
NetBackup/ homes/     pgsql/     tmp/
user01@NAS:/$ ls -ld var/services/
NetBackup/ homes/     pgsql/     tmp/
user01@NAS:/$ ls -ld var/services/homes
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Oct  4 13:42 var/services/homes -> /volume1/homes
user01@NAS:/$ ls -ld var/services/homes/user01/
drwxr-x--- 1 user01 users 90 Oct  3 09:41 var/services/homes/user01/
user01@NAS:/$ ls -ld var/services/homes/user01/.ssh/
drwx------ 1 user01 users 30 Oct  4 13:59 var/services/homes/user01/.ssh/
user01@NAS:/$ ls -ls var/services/homes/user01/.ssh/authorized_keys
4 -rw------- 1 user01 users 571 Oct  4 13:59 var/services/homes/user01/.ssh/authorized_keys
user01@NAS:/$
```

For the local machine:
/Users/user02/.ssh/id_rsa
/Users/user02/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

```
[@/]$ ls -ld Users
drwxr-xr-x  6 root  admin   192B Jan  1  2020 Users/
[@/]$ ls -ld Users/user02
drwxr-xr-x+ 152 user02  staff   4.8K Oct  4 13:58 Users/user02/
[@/]$ ls -ld Users/user02/.ssh
drwx------  7 user02  staff   224B Oct  4 13:59 Users/user02/.ssh/
[@/]$ ls -la Users/user02/.ssh/id_rsa
-rw-------  1 user02  staff   2.6K Oct  4 13:58 Users/user02/.ssh/id_rsa
[@/]$ ls -la Users/user02/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 user02  staff   571B Oct  4 13:58 Users/user02/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
[@/]$
```

How is it possible to be able organize that I give (for instance) only once (the first time) the key?

Comment: ssh agent should ask the password once and keep it (until a selected timeout). Or do you mean: having just one ssh connection to do all tasks (so you get passphrase only once)?

Comment: thank you for your comment @GiacomoCatenazzi. Well that's the problem: it asks me the password at each copying of dir to be copied (which can hapen in time range of seconds)

Comment: Given your local file structure, and assuming a ssh agent is running anyway, can you try if running `ssh-add -t 60` is of help for you? It will prompt for passwords once, will add keys in the default locations (like you have) to the ssh-agent, and remove them after 60 seconds. While the key is in the agent, you shouldn't be prompted for the password again.

Comment: That's great! @UlrichSchwarz! It helped a lot. Let's say now that I set the value to a high number (e.g. 6000), I run the bash script which eventually finishes and then I want to stop the command (so that the password will get prompted again). Is there a way to do that. If you want to post an answer, I'll be glad to accept it